# ajax keep pressing submit and page was like lagging

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
    //username validation
    function checkusername(){
        var username_value = $("#reg-username").val();
        var userpass;
        if(username_value === ""){
            //username empty
            $("#user-result").html('Please choose a username.');
            $('#user-result').css('color', 'red');
            $('#reg-username').css('border-color', 'red');
        }else if (username_value.length < 4){
            //username atless 4 digi
            $("#user-result").html('Your username is too short.');
            $('#user-result').css('color', 'red');
            $('#reg-username').css('border-color', 'red');
        }else if (username_value.length >= 4){
         $.ajax({  
          type:"POST",  
          url:'class/classvalidation.php',  
          async:false,
          data:{'username':username_value},  
          success: function(data){  
              var usernameAvailable = JSON.parse(data);
                var color = usernameAvailable.exists ? '#dfe0e6' : 'red';
                $("#user-result").html(usernameAvailable.message);
                $('#user-result').css('color', color);
                $("#reg-username").css('border-color', color);
                if(usernameAvailable.exists === true){
                    userpass = true;
                }else{
                    userpass = false;
                }
              }
            });
            };

            //return function value
            if(userpass === true){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            };  
    }

   //jquery started
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#reg-username").keyup(checkusername);
   $(document).click(function() {
        $(document).on("submit", '#contact-form', function(){
            checkusername();
            if(!checkusername()){
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#othersubmit-result").css('color', 'red');
            $("#othersubmit-result").html('sumbit not requirements.');
            // window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            return false;
            }else{
            $("#othersubmit-result").css('color', 'green');
            $("#othersubmit-result").html('sumbit passed.');
            return true;
            }
            });
        });
   });

</script>
```

index.php

```
<form id="contact-form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method=post>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="reg-username"  placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off"/><br>
        <span id="user-result"></span>
        <div id="register_submit_content"><input type="submit" name="othersubmit" id="othersubmit" value="Sign Up"/></div>
        <span id="othersubmit-result"></span>
    </form>
```

this is a live check validation , checking any same username name exitis in my database , and the ajax is connect to mysql , mysql part have no problem. but if the input detect have same username and i keep clicking submit button , the page will be like lagging or hang  for a while , like loading. how do i fix this ? and what wrong ? i guess was the ajax sending multiple form ?

Comment: Disable the button until previous ajax request completes

Comment: on every key change ajax call performs and it could not handled properly.Dont make second ajax call untill you get response from first call

Comment: Change code for else if (username_value.length >= 4){ //Disable Submit button and on ajax Success //Enable 
Submit button to make second ajax request enable to call.